# When using ActiveX to write to Excel from Javascript, border types and line styles are not recognized

Tags: javascript, excel, activex, export-to-excel, vba

I recently found that when I was writing to an excel file via ActiveX from an aspx / html page and using javascript, that the macros/vba code you see in the Excel IDE do not match up compeltely.

For example - 
In Excel, If you record a macro when you remove the border of a cell, you would see something like this:

```
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```

but if you wanted to do that same action from JS via active X, that code would not be recognized. (Answer below)

Answer (score 1):

The above code would be written such as:

```
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(5).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(6).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(7).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(8).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(9).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(10).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(11).LineStyle = -4142;
ws.Range("A1:Z65536").Borders(12).LineStyle = -4142;
```

because there are numeric mappings to each position and LineStyle. From [here](http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2007/01/setting-excel-borders-from-vbscript-or.html#!/2007/01/setting-excel-borders-from-vbscript-or.html):

```
These define the style of the border
xlNone = -4142; Note this is the same as xlLineStyleNone
xlContinuous = 1;
xlDash = -4115;
xlDashDot = 4;
xlDashDotDot = 5;
xlDot = -4118;
xlDouble = -4119;
xlSlantDashDot = 13;

These define the weight of the border
xlHairLine = 1;
xlMedium = -4138;
xlThick = 4;
xlThin = 2;

Thise is handy to make borders have the default color index
xlAutomatic = -4105;

These define the placement of border pieces
xlDiagonalDown = 5;
xlDiagonalUp = 6;
xlEdgeLeft = 7;
xlEdgeTop = 8;
xlEdgeBottom = 9;
xlEdgeRight = 10;
xlInsideVertical = 11;
xlInsideHorizontal = 12;
```